# Making custom regular expression to C# compatible

Tags: c#, regex

I tried to use following regular expression in C#:

```
@(<h3 class=\"r\"><a href=\")([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?
```

But I am getting error in visual studio.  I want to test this expression against:

```
<h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=http://example.com/
```

Whats am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use an HTML parser.

Comment: string lookup = @"(<h3 class=\"r\"><a href=\")([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?";

Comment: "I am getting error" is not a useful problem description. What **specific error** are you getting, including the **exact** error message? You have that information available right in front of you, and we can't see your screen from here. There's no reason for you not to provide the error details in your question to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Error is : semicolon ( ; ) expected .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes in literal strings are escaped by doubling them (`""`), not with backslashes.
Your string literal is ending prematurely.